# How to save an array with one metakey in postmeta?

Tags: post-meta

I have an array saved in postmata, each array key become a metakey. I want to change the code to save the whole array with one metakey. How to do that? Thanks!

```
$poddata = Array(
'pod_id' => $this->pod_id,
'url' => $this->url,
'name' => $this->name,
'description' => $this->description,
'service' => $this->service,
'status' =>$this->status,
'price' => $this->price
);

foreach ( $poddata as $k => $v ){

if ( get_post_meta( $this->id, $k ) == '' )
add_post_meta( $this->id, $meta_box, $v, true );

elseif ( $v != get_post_meta( $this->id, $k, true ) )
update_post_meta( $this->id, $k, $v );

elseif ( $v == '' )
delete_post_meta( $this->id, $k, get_post_meta( $this->id, $k, true ) );

}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You don't need to loop through the values. Just use `update_post_meta($post_ID, {key}, {array of vals})`, it should do!

```
<?php
$poddata = Array(
    'pod_id' => $this->pod_id,
    'url' => $this->url,
    'name' => $this->name,
    'description' => $this->description,
    'service' => $this->service,
    'status' =>$this->status,
    'price' => $this->price
    );

//Update inserts a new entry if it doesn't exist, updates otherwise
update_post_meta($post_ID, 'poddata', $poddata);
?>
```

Thats it! When you fetch it for usage, do the following:

```
    $poddata = get_post_meta($post_ID, 'poddata');
```

$poddata is the array of values.

Comment: I tried update_post_meta($post_ID, 'poddata', $postdata), after save the post, i see the meta is not saved.

Comment: oh, sorry, It saved, I didn't see it on WP Custom Fields Table.  I just found it in phpAdmin. Thanks!

Comment: When retrive the data, by get_post_meta($post_ID, 'poddata');
I get array(0) from var_dump. How can I get the whole array?

Comment: You're welcome!
Try using print_r()... 
echo "<pre>";
print_r($poddata);
echo "</pre>";

Comment: print_r($poddata) shows Array()

Comment: Ohh... then the values aren't stored. You're getting an empty array. I tried the example locally, and it worked fine. Try a print_r of the array of values before you update_post_meta. It's probably not getting any values.

Comment: It's stored, I can see it in phpAdmin, new posts has metakey of "pod" and and value of the array. Just can't fetch it.

Comment: Try `$poddata = get_post_meta($post_ID, 'poddata',true);`

Comment: Jenny, Try the above solution too.

@Bainternet
I deliberately skipped the third parameter, which is the 'single' flag, as the meta value is an array in get_post_meta. Is it required when dealing with arrays instead of strings as meta values? I use it only when I store strings as meta values.

Comment: Great!!! the "true" works! Thanks!!!

Comment: The true 3rd parameter should be skipped if you have more then one fields with the same name, it value can be a string,boolean,integer or array but that is not what this parameter is about.

Comment: Thanks! Now I've a clear understanding of the 'true' parameter!

Comment: It updates or insert. But does it also deletes items that don't exist in the new array?